# Speeding up processing of geotiff background for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, tiles

Originally I had an image as a mrsid file.  That was very convenient as it was smaller and fast to pan etc.  The down side was that every time I upgraded QGIS I had to go through the ritual of reinstalling the mrsid stuff (I am on a Mac if that matters).

So I recently made a GeoTIFF of the image -- this works fine but doing anything that involves redrawing the image is slow.  I know that I can use gdal to produce a pyramid tiles and that this is the way web apps deal with the issue but I am unsure if that is the best approach for QGIS.

If it is the best approach then pointers to a tutorial would help greatly -- there are a lot of parameters to play with!

Comment: Tiled geotiff with overviews is the standard way. With GDAL it means -co tiled=yes and running gdaladdo.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation that I am on right track. I have been looking at the various gdal utilities and it is not at all clear how I should proceed. I have the run gdal2tiles on the geotiff file which has produced a directory of stuff but I have no idea how to use this in QGIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some fiddling and a lot of googling I found that this worked

```
gdal_translate -co tiled=yes -a_srs EPSG:27200 tiff/Tiri  tiff/Tiri-tiled
gdaladdo tiff/Tiri-tiled
```

Where  `tiff/Tiri` was the original GeoTIFF file that I produced from the mrsid file.

Comment: Right. Find how to optimize tiffs for MapServer and GeoServer and you will learn more about compression if you want to save space. Overviews you can make also with QGIS (pyramids). Search "GeoServer on steroids" is a good start and the tiff recipes are good for QGIS too.